# CSS3 Animation Bubble Effect for Hexagonal Shape

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

i have done bubble effect for circle and now i'am trying to do it in hexagonal shape through css. but the result is not expected.

[Circle DEMO](https://fiddle.jshell.net/4whohz3t/)

[Hexagonal DEMO 1](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1tp1qbn3/)

[Hexagonal DEMO 2](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ovwfys3p/)

can some one please shed some light !!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid what you try to achieve is not possible. When you create the hexagon you are using borders to create a couple of triangles but the shadow will not be thrown with this shape. CSS shadow property throws the shadow of the containing box.

You can achieve a shadow on a hexagon (or any figure you want) using SVG

```
.hex{
  fill: #64C7CC;
  filter: url(#dropshadow);
}

<svg width="100%" height="300">
  <defs xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <filter id="dropshadow" height="130%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3"/> 
      <feOffset dx="2" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/> 
      <feMerge> 
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/> 
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <polygon class="hex" points="300,150 225,280 75,280 0,150 75,20 225,20"></polygon>
</svg>
```

and then use a bit of javascript to work out the animation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will give a try with this !!